# Sorting integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm something of a beginner to the art and science of algorithms,and as I was learning about "Quick Sort" (which is allegedly quite fast) I had an idea for a sort that uses a dictionary. I coded it up, and I was quite surprised that for what I was interested in (sorting, say, earth temperatures or elevation data) that what I had coded up was actually **faster** than C# .NET's List.Sort() once I compiled it in Release mode. For example, if I create a list of one million integers loaded with values ranging from zero to 8000 (a good range for typical Earth elevations), the .NET List.Sort() method averages about 88 milliseconds to sort the list, while the algo below does so in about 58 milliseconds. 
So this gets me thinking that I should either be up for the Nobel prize for computer science (unlikely) or that there is something that I am missing and that there is a much more efficient way of sorting a large number of integers in the range say of zero to 10,000. How would you experts sort a large amount of data in that range?

```
private static long DictionarySort(List<int> myList, out List<int> sortedList)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    int max = myList.Max();
    Dictionary<int, int> sorter = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    int myListCount = myList.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < myListCount; i++)
    {
        int val = myList[i];
        int occurances = 0;
        sorter[val] = sorter.TryGetValue(val, out occurances) ? occurances + 1 : 1;
    }
    sortedList = new List<int>(myList.Count + 1);
    int numOccur = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if (sorter.TryGetValue(i, out numOccur))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numOccur; j++)
            {
                sortedList.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you're getting a lot of speedup from the fact that if you're sorting a million integers between 0 and 8k you're going to have a lot of overlap - circa 125 instances of each, so you're going to get lots of cases where elements dont need swapping.

Comment: This is related to counting sort or radix sort — more efficient than the standard sorting algorithms, but only when the number of possible values is significantly smaller than the size of the array.

Comment: Also it's "occurrences" :)

Comment: Along similar lines as PaulJWilliams' comment, QuickSort is not known to be particularly effective when sorting data with relatively few distinct keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've rediscovered what Wikipedia calls [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), a very simple distribution sorting algorithm.  It is the optimal algorithm for your data set: it runs in O(N + k) time (N is number of records and k is number of distinct keys), uses O(k) additional storage, and has very low coefficients.

Comment: +1 I was busy typing this out when you answered. :-)

Comment: Not just Wikipedia!  This has been called counting sort for a lot longer than Wikipedia has existed!